# Find all possible exclusively intersection of multiple sets python

Tags: python, set, python-itertools

As per title, given *n* sets like the following:

```
set1 = {"aa","ab","ba","cc","ca"},
set2 = {"fr","fa","po","pl","cc"},
set3 = {"fr","xz","hn","fa"},
set4 = {"jq","we","hn","ca","aa","fk"},
set5 = {"jp","wx","we","fr","ba"}
```

I want to get the exclusively intersections between them, conceptually like a Venn Diagram representation. So, for example:

---

The intersection between the `set2` and `set3`, despite sharing `{"fr","fa"}`, will only be `{"fa"}`, as the string `"fr"` is also present in the intersection between `set2`,`set3` and `set5`.

---

The brilliant solution proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56552470/9300441) managed correctly all the permutations of given sets, but didn't manage to account for exclusivity, considering each overlap independently. So, in the previous example, it'll return `{"fr","fa"}`

#### Tryout

I tried to handle this situation in a very slow way, and want to know if there's a more proficient way to do the job.
By creating a list of sets

```
set_list = [set1, set2, set3, set4, set5]
```

I start from finding the whole sets intersection

```
whole_intersect = set.intersections(*map(set,set_list))
```

Then I'm moving in every permutation of length `n-1` using list indices

```
isect_1_2_3_4 = set.intersections(*map(set, map(set_list.__getitem__, [0,1,2,3])) - whole_intersect
isect_1_2_3_5 = set.intersections(*map(set, map(set_list.__getitem__, [0,1,2,5])) - whole_intersect
..
```

Then by `n-2`

```
isect_1_2_3 = set.intersections(*map(set, map(set_list.__getitem__, [0,1,2])) - whole_intersect - isect_1_2_3_4 - isect_1_2_3_5
..
```

Till filling intersections of 2 sets

```
isect_1_2 = set.intersections(*map(set, map(set_list.__getitem__, [0,1,2])) - whole_intersect - isect_1_2_3_4 - isect_1_2_3_5 - isect_1_2_3 - isect_1_2_4 - isect_1_2_5
..
```

As expectable, this approach is a true pain. How could I manage to do it in a less handcrafted and pythonic way?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have done it by first making a dictionary of all of the intersections, of every combination, and then finding the unique intersection by taking the intersection and subtracting the union of every other intersection:

```
import itertools

set1 = {"aa","ab","ba","cc","ca"}
set2 = {"fr","fa","po","pl","cc"}
set3 = {"fr","xz","hn","fa"}
set4 = {"jq","we","hn","ca","aa","fk"}
set5 = {"jp","wx","we","fr","ba"}
sets = {
    1: set1,
    2: set2,
    3: set3,
    4: set4,
    5: set5
}

intersections = {}
for n_combinations in range(2, len(sets) + 1):
    tmp = list(map(dict, itertools.combinations(sets.items(), n_combinations)))
    tmp = {tuple(x.keys()):set.intersection(*list(x.values())) for x in tmp}
    intersections.update(tmp)

unique_in_intersection = {}
for n_combinations in range(2, len(sets)+1):
    for lookup_set in itertools.combinations(range(1, len(sets)+1), n_combinations):
        s1_intersection_s2 = intersections[lookup_set]
        union_other_intersections = set.union(*[v for k, v in intersections.items() if k != lookup_set and len(k) > len(lookup_set)])
        unique_in_intersection[lookup_set] = s1_intersection_s2 - union_other_intersections
```

result:

```
{
    (1, 2): {'cc'},
    (1, 3): set(),
    (1, 4): {'ca', 'aa'},
    (1, 5): {'ba'},
    (2, 3): {'fa'},
    (2, 4): set(),
    (2, 5): set(),
    (3, 4): {'hn'},
    (3, 5): set(),
    (4, 5): {'we'},
    (1, 2, 3): set(),
    (1, 2, 4): set(),
    (1, 2, 5): set(),
    (1, 3, 4): set(),
    (1, 3, 5): set(),
    (1, 4, 5): set(),
    (2, 3, 4): set(),
    (2, 3, 5): {'fr'},
    (2, 4, 5): set(),
    (3, 4, 5): set(),
    (1, 2, 3, 4): set(),
    (1, 2, 3, 5): set(),
    (1, 2, 4, 5): set(),
    (1, 3, 4, 5): set(),
    (2, 3, 4, 5): set(),
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5): set()
}
```

Comment: Fine, thanks for the provided example. I was doing it manually to keep an hierarchy, where a string will be present only in the largest (in term of intersected sets) intersection, to preserve the Venn Diagram logic (see in detail the Tryout section).

Comment: @Shred I am not sure what you mean by your comment. Hopefully, my answer generalizes to any number of sets, however.

Comment: Sorry, the question isn't clear at all.
From the toy example, the intersection `2_3_5` must contain the string `"fr"`, as none of the intersections of higher length containing all these three sets (so `1_2_3_4_5`, `2_3_4_5`, `1_2_3_5`) has the same string inside. So, given an intersection of *n* sets, each string has to be checked for exclusivity only against intersections of *j* sets, where j > n, and where each set of the n-long intersection is inside the j-long one. Hope it sounds clearer now.

Comment: @Shed I modified my answer, and now gets the correct result.